# Is this good practice regarding security and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, security

I would just like to have some feedback on some php code for a website, because it's the first time I'm writing code that will properly be used on public websites and I'm a little paranoid.

This code is at the top of a signup page with a post form that sends back to itself, so I check if the form has been completed by checking if the POST "isset".

It's for a signup page :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $thanks = '';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode']; //not used
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    //connects to database, DB variable is dbConnection
    require_once("include/database_connect_test.php");

    //First check email isn't already on DB
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `user_profile` WHERE email=?';

    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();


    $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if($num_of_rows>0)
        $thanks = 'This email has already been registered';

    //If not, create profile
    else{

        require_once('generate_uuid.php');

        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); //password_verify(pass, hash) to verify



        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `user_profile`(`name`, `email`, `hash`, `uuid`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';

        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $hash, $uuid);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();


        $thanks = 'Thank you for signing up!'; //used in the html
    }
}?>
```

Thanks in advance for any input :)

Comment: You should probably add some extra-sanitization using mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlpurifier, even though you're using prepared statements

Comment: you must check if all $_POST vars are set before put it in a var. so you can use email with void password and your code will run normally and crash when try to do  $password = $_POST['password'];
Check this and pay attention to Jojo01's comment. Cheers!

Comment: Depends on what security aspect you are looking at. For example, if you're protecting against automated registration, use recaptcha. To protect attack on username/email, instead of replying email has already been registered, just reply with a thank you and send an email to that address indicating that it has already been registered before. And much more, really.

Comment: Right now someone is able to for example put javascript as his username, and if you added a comments section that javascript would run. Your script is vulnerable to xss injection. Use mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlpurifier.

Comment: Thanks everyone, will do!

Comment: Good for you for for being paranoid and for using `password_hash()`

Comment: @Jojo01 No, please don't! Treating everything as HTML and double-escaping input is just a way to corrupt user data and add no extra security.

Comment: plus one for being paranoid.

Comment: @Jojo01 that is nonsense, XSS injection becomes an issue when outputting content to webpage, not when inserting to database. You should store the content as it is, and do html encoding if you are outputting data on a webpage.

Comment: @1615903 Well, that's another way of doing It.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code review and should be posted in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jojo01 why would you care if somebody uses javascript as their username? Just `htmlspecialchars` it. Also there is no reason at all for `mysqli_real_escape_string` because OP is using prepared statements and bound parameters.

Comment: @1615903 ah fair enough, I didn't know the codereview forum existed !

Answer (score 3):

I see nothing particularly wrong from the security standpoint. You're doing the most important things right:

- Use a MySQL extension that's currently supported
- Use prepared statements
- Hash passwords with `password_hash()`

Being picky:

- The fact that `$_POST['email']` is set doesn't imply other post variables will also exist. You should really verify *all* input because filling your form is not the only way to submit data to your script. But rather than *security* is a way to ensure you can take benefit of PHP notices by avoiding false positives.

  Also, you may like the filter extension, a feature that's been available for a while but is not particularly widespread and allows code like this:

  ```
  $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
  $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
  $postcode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'postcode'); //not used
  $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
  ```
- I've never liked the technique of counting rows in a result set to validate if a user exists because it's too dependent on external factors (database driver, query function used...). I simply fetch the row, which also allows to retrieve additional user data for session variables.
- I suppose that `$uuid` is defined inside `generate_uuid.php` but when you look at code it seems to pop up from nowhere. A better structure is that your included files load functions and then you call those functions:

  ```
  $uuid = generate_uuid();
  $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $hash, $uuid);
  ```

... but, as I said, none of these factors affect security.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small collection of PHP features and functions that can be useful to your code block:

- [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), check that the string email address `$_POST['email']` is a valid email shape:

> ```
>  if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){...}
> ```

- You really should set the `$options['cost']` value for your [`Password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). THe default standard is 10 which is a bit weak, depending on your server specs I would say you want *at least* 12 cost value.

> ```
> $options['cost'] = 12;
> $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);
> ```

- I  would recommend running your `$_POST` variables through a custom stripper function such as a `preg_replace` Regex. I would personally always use a Regex routine to strip out unwanted characters from a submitted string.
- Your `uuid` value with the name of `id` I would expect it to be a counter integer but it's cast to the binding as a string(`S`), so not sure about what type of variable that is?
- Also  you can improve your security by researching and looking into [Cross Site Scripting](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/how-to-prevent-cross-site-scripting-attacks/) and how to avoid this, basically set a unique value in your submitting form, and save this value to a `$_SESSION` and then compare, this will much more ensure that things sent to your PHP / MySQL will come and be accepted only from *your* sending form.
- On a related security note, you can also setup a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) header for your website.

Comment: Is strip tags bad? I know it can screw up unbalanced tags, but tag elements shouldn't really be in the text fields, I imagine @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: `strip_tags()` is an HTML manipulation function (and not a very good one because it doesn't use a proper DOM parser). It has no place as a general purpose tool because most things in life are not HTML (in this same question we have name, email, postcode ans password) and even when we do have HTML we don't normally want to remove tags blindly (if so, why ask for HTML in the first place?).

Answer (score 1):

1. User enumeration. Use a 2-step registration (w email link)
2. You are not preventing high-speed robotic registrations
3. You are not confirming the user's email address or password (they might have typed it wrong. Most sites use a "confirm password" form field)
4. Not validating data (is email really an email, is password ten spaces?)

Unrelated to security, you should use the Post-Redirect-Get pattern. For now, when user sees "Thanks" message, if they hit "refresh" on their browser, it will try to re-register them.

Answer (score 0):

Right now someone is able to for example put javascript as his username, and if you added a comments section that javascript would run. Your script is vulnerable to xss injection. Use mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlpurifier.

Comment: If your app processes user names as if they were JavaScript code you have bigger problems...

Comment: This is total nonsense. This script does no HTML or script output, so there is no possible HTML/script-injection issue, and it doesn't put strings into queries, so there is no need for SQL escaping. Putting SQL handling onto a string that isn't SQL or HTML purification onto a string that isn't HTML just results in mangling. For example if you ‘purified’ a password of `<potato>`, you'd end up with an empty password.